# Does Google provide a http page to return a XML route?

Tags: http, google-maps, routes

I have been using a lot of Google Maps's API for getting geocoding and reverse geocoding services.

Do you know if there's a service (through http) that would return a route?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use [DirectionService](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#DirectionsService) from the Maps API.

Comment: Hello! But this is a javascript class, right?
I would need a http page that would return the XML. do you have the link?

Answer (score 0):

... and if you are using the Version 2 API, you can use [GDirection](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections) class.

I thought I should clarify that both the [v3](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/v3/basics.html) DirectionService and [v2](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/) GDirection classes are part of the JavaScript Google Maps API.

If you are looking to access the Google Maps API Geocoding Service directly over HTTP then as far as I know you are limited to [Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding requests](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

It is quite possible that this service does exist and I have missed it (please let me know if this is the case).

Comment: Dear cannonade.
yes, that's exatly what I am looking for, a http page that would return a rout xml or JSON.
Anyway, if I have to link to my own http page and put the javascript code, will it generate the XML?

Thanks again!